# Need to alter response headers for error pages

Tags: http-request

We have Cloudflare sitting in front of our Drupal sites - and in order to take advantage of their "AlwaysOnline" feature - we need to alter the response code sent in the event of an error.

I want to cater for when the database is unavailable - as this can sometimes happen when upgrading the MySQL server.

The only way I've found so far is to hack the errors.inc file:

```
if ($fatal) {
    drupal_add_http_header('Status', '504 Service unavailable (with message)');
  }
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve what I'm after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`template_preprocess_maintenance_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_maintenance_page/7.x) invocation in your theme's **template.php** so that when you go to maintenance mode (or the DB is down) it will trigger your needed status code:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_maintenance_page(&$variables) {
  drupal_add_http_header('Status', '504 Service unavailable (with message)');
}
```

Comment: This works great for the regular maintenance page - but when the Database is down - in order for the theme hook to fire, I set this in my settings: $conf['maintenance_theme'] = 'zurb_neway'; This in turn then calls system_list() to get all modules... so the page never renders?

Comment: I got this working by adding your code to a simpler theme in /sites/all/themes/bartik - this now works across all my multi-site install - so great work!